# Replacing spaces with underscores within quotes

Tags: regex, vim, sed, substitution

I need to replace within a large text file all occurrences such as `'yw234DV w-23-sDf wef23s-d-f'` with the same strings but with underscores instead of spaces for all spaces within quotes, without replacing any spaces outside quotes with underscores.

I'm trying to find a solution for substitution within vim, but a sed solution would also be much appreciated. The number of tokens in each quote-delimited string may vary.

I've been playing with some regexes in vim, but they're pretty elementary and seem to be missing what I need.

My current attempt:

```
%s/'{[:alnum:] }*/'\0\_/g
```

And I'm experimenting with variations on that.

This is most similar to my question, though it is Java:
[Replacing spaces within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478038/replacing-spaces-within-quotes)

Sample Input:

```
'wiUEF7-gvouw ow wo24-RTeih we', 'yt23IT iug-76'
```

Sample Output:

```
'wiUEF7-gvouw_ow_wo24-RTeih_we', 'yt23IT_iug-76'
```

Comment: Do you want to replace _all_ spaces inside of _any_ single-quoted string with underscores?  Or, are there other restrictions?

Comment: Also, show what you have tried so far and describe in what way it failed.  Without showing your effort, people think that you are asking for free consulting and many people here don't like that.

Comment: Please show proper sample Input_file with proper sample expected output(apart from what is being asked by John1024 too).

Comment: Thanks I've edited the question. I'm just plugging away attempts in vim...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this with VIM, tried this on Macvim:

```
%s/\%('[^']*'\)*\('[^']*'\)/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', '_', 'g')/g
```

Much simpler solution , Thanks to @SergioAraujo:

```
@%s/\v%(('[^']*'))/\=substitute(submatch(1),' ', '_', 'g')/g
```

Not sure however, if below is the outcome you have expected
Output:

```
'wiUEF7-gvouw_ow_wo24-RTeih_we', 'yt23IT_iug-76'
```

Comment: Is it possible to use very magic in this solution to make it more readable?

Comment: @SergioAraujo `%s/\v%('[^']*')*('[^']*')/\=substitute(submatch(1), ' ', '_', 'g')/g`

Comment: Once we have the same pattern twice on the regex match we can group it, isn't? `%s/\v%(('[^']*'))/\=substitute(submatch(1),' ', '_', 'g')/g`

Comment: @SergioAraujo, Thanks It does and probably always work

Answer (score 3):

In perl:

```
perl -i -pe's{(\x27.*?\x27)}{ (my $subst = $1) =~ tr/ /_/ }ge'  yourfile
```

or with perl5.14 or above:

```
perl -i -pe's{(\x27.*?\x27)}{ $1 =~ tr/ /_/r }ge'
```

Answer (score 2):

With this the input file:

```
$ cat file
'wiUEF7-gvouw ow wo24-RTeih we', 'yt23IT iug-76'
```

We can convert all spaces inside of single-quotes into underscores with:

```
$ sed -E ":a; s/^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*)[[:space:]]/\1_/; ta" file
'wiUEF7-gvouw_ow_wo24-RTeih_we', 'yt23IT_iug-76'
```

#### How it works

1. `:a`

   This creates a label `a`.
2. `s/^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*)[[:space:]]/\1_/`

   This inserts the underscores where we want them.

   - `^(([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*)[[:space:]]`

     This looks for any odd number of single quotes followed by any number of non-quote characters followed by a space.  Everything before that space is saved in group 1.
   - `\1_`

     This replaces the matched text with group 1 followed by an underscore.
3. `ta`

   If the previous command put any new underscores in the string, then jump back to label `a` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `FPAT` variable in `gnu awk` you can do this:

```
awk -v OFS=', ' -v FPAT="'[^']*'" '{for (h=1; h<=NF; h++) 
{gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "_", $h); printf "%s%s", $h, (h < NF ? OFS : ORS)}}' file

'wiUEF7-gvouw_ow_wo24-RTeih_we', 'yt23IT_iug-76'
```

Comment: This assumes your text is of the pattern: `'text', 'text'`. If it deviates: `'text', foo, 'text'` then using `FPAT` will drop the `foo` part of your text.

Comment: Some assumption is always there. e.g. you are assuming input is comma delimited but OP hasn't mentioned it anywhere.  Though it can be handled using `-v FPAT="'[^']*'|[^,' ]+"`